# lxml ns_clean=True does not appear to work

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

The following code:

```
NAMESPACES = {'ns': 'http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5', 'ns1': 'http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9'}
ro_xml = '{}.xml'.format(6001265)
parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True)
tree = etree.parse(ro_xml)
root = etree.tostring(tree.getroot())
# print root
residence = []
residence_address = '//ns:ResidenceAddress/*'
shop_supplies_amount = tree.xpath(residence_address, namespaces=NAMESPACES)
for child in shop_supplies_amount:
    residence.append("%s: %s" % (child.tag, child.text))
print residence
```

When I run this I am getting the namespaces in front of the tag names like so `'{http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5}LineOne: 10757 RIVER FRONT PARKWAY'`

What am I doing incorrectly and how do I get rid of the namespace in front of the tag names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a way around it.

```
NAMESPACES = {'ns': 'http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5', 'ns1': 'http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9'}
ro_xml = '{}.xml'.format(6001265)
parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True)
tree = etree.parse(ro_xml, parser)

vehicle = {}
vehicle_info = tree.xpath(twc.XML_VEHICLE_INFO, namespaces=NAMESPACES)
for child in vehicle_info:
    vehicle.update({child.tag: child.text})
model = residence['{%s}Model' % NAMESPACES['ns']]
print model
```

Not the cleanest I admit, but it gets me where I need to be.